# What's "static function" supposed to mean in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the book "Learning Spark" is a sentence that bewilders me. It says

> In Scala, we can pass in functions defined inline, references to methods, or static functions as we do for Scala's other functional APIs. (page 31)

"functions defined inline" refers to something like `(x, y) => x + y` I guess. But what is meant my the other two things?

"references to methods" would be something like

```
class SearchFunctions(val query: String) extends Serializable {

    private def isMatch(s: String): Boolean = {
        s.contains(query)
    }

    def getMatchesFunctionReference(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[Boolean] = {
        rdd.map(isMatch)
    }
}

new SearchFunctions("hello").getMatchesFunctionReference(myrdd).collect
```

I would guess. But what is meant with a "static function"? After all Scala does not have anything static, so what do the authors mean?

Comment: The easiest, and only reliable, way to find out what the authors mean, ist to ask them. Anything else is just pure speculation.

Comment: My wild guess would go with methods defined on Scala objects.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it refers to functions defined in `object`s, and functions assigned to variables, fields, or parameters.

You are right about what "functions defined inline", and "references to methods" mean.